# Тире открылось, но не закрылось, - мешает придаточное (оборот с "несмотря")?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> Предназначение ***царского дома*** <базилики> – давать место большому стечению
>   людей, несмотря на светское своё устройство, неким образом
>   соответствовало ведению первой литургии.

Да, тут ещё что-то не так: *Предназначение <...>, несмотря на светское своё устройство*, и далее до конца.

А речь-то о базилике, а не о предназначении, О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Предназначение царского дома <базилики> – давать место большому стечению людей, несмотря на светское ЕГО устройство, — неким образом соответствовало ведению первой литургии.**

Второй вариант:

**Предназначение царского дома <базилики> – давать место большому стечению людей — неким образом соответствовало требованиям к первой литургии, несмотря на светское устройство базилики.**

Comment: Кого ж - ЕЕ? Базилика в угловых скобках, её нет в предложении. И что у нас получилось: *Предназначение... неким образом соответствовало ведению первой литургии*?

Comment: Я добавил второй вариант